# Why Link2SD requires second partition on sdcard for linking?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, link2sd

Why can't it simply link to extSdCard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If it would use the only partition of your SDCard, apps would become unavailable if that card is mounted to e.g. your PC via UMS (USB mass storage). That's what happens with *App2SD*, and *Link2SD* wants to avoid that.
2. Ever tried creating links on FAT (which is the [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) used on your card). This adds to the problem.
3. Using a separate partition, *Link2SD* can make use of "advanced" [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) types, e.g. ext3/ext4, which leads (amongst other things) to better performance. Doing so with your only SDCard partition, this would introduce problems for Windows users, as Windows doesn't support EXT file systems out-of-the-box

These are the most obvious reasons for this decision. It might very well be I missed some more -- but these alone are enough to make it a wise decision :)

Comment: Weird, on my device (Samsung S3 Mini) partition is not unmounted when connected to PC. In fact I'm using FolderMount with my extSdCard and it's working perfectly fine...

Comment: Your device probably doesn't use UMS but MTP. With UMS, storage is granted *exclusively* (hence it becomes unavailable on the device, and can be accessed on block-level if needed), while with MTP it is *shared* (and hence available on both ends, but no block-level access is possible from the PC). See the [usb-mass-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-mass-storage/info) for details.